# Difference between these 2 ways of finding Random Numbers?

Tags: java, random

For example, if I were to generate random numbers between 5 and 50, I know I could write the code as either:

```
ranNum = (int)Math.random()*(50-5+1)+5;
```

Or

```
ranNum = Math.round(Math.random()*(50-5))+5;
```

In terms of the process to generate the random numbers, what is the difference between the two? And which would be faster?

Comment: That's the point, they're not. What's the difference though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Speed is not important here.

```
ranNum = (int)Math.random()*(50-5+1)+5;
```

This produces a random number between 5 and 50 where each number has an equal chance of occurring.

---

```
ranNum = Math.round(Math.random()*(50-5))+5;
```

This produces a random number between 5 and 50 however 5 and 50 have half the chance of occuring as the others i.e. before ronding the values has to be < 5.5 to get 5 and >= 49.5 to get 50.

---

Note: neither is the fastest way to generate a random number in a range.

```
int n = random.nextInt(50 - 5 + 1) + 5;
```

This is faster because it uses less random bits.